# Не удается достать pathPrefix из intent-filter

Tags: android, android-studio

В Activity нужно достать строчку topone (android:pathPrefix="/topone") из intent-filter:

```
<activity android:name=".MenuActivity">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="app"
                    android:host="project.myproject.name"
                    android:pathPrefix="/topone" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Для этого я пыталась получить data и вывести в лог, но ничего не выводится:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        String str = String.valueOf(uri);
        Log.d("myLogs", str);
```

Comment: Поясните поподробнее что Вы хотите, для чего Вам эта строчка и где нужно её получить? Так как Вы пробовали можно получить uri в самой этой активности, при условии что она запущена неявным интентом прошедшим этот фильтр.

Comment: woesss, мне это нужно для DeepLinks

Comment: Но зачем Вам узнавать префикс в коде, если он заранее известен - Вы ведь его туда собственноручно вписали?

Comment: woesss, мне нужно достать intent.getData() в коде, но почему-то uri равно null

Comment: То есть Вам всё-таки нужен адрес ссылки, по которой пришли в активность, а не запись в манифесте? Тогда, собственно, приведённый код выполняется в `MenuActivity`? И если да, то как она была запущена?

Comment: woesss, Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы что-то получить - надо что-то положить:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class); 
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("app://project.myproject.name/topone/bla-bla"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

- именно эту uri-строку Вы получите в `MenuActivity`.
При запуске явным интентом (когда указан класс активности и пакет/контекст приложения) `intent-filter` не играет никакой роли - системе не зачем его проверять когда цель известна.
Чтобы проверить Ваш фильтр нужно послать неявный интент:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("app://project.myproject.name/topone/bla-bla"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Или через `adb`:

```
$ adb shell am start
        -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW
        -d <URI> <PACKAGE>
```

Пример:

```
$ adb shell am start
    -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW
    -d "app://project.myproject.name/topone/bla-bla" your.application.id
```

[(документация)](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#testing-filters)